# Selenium Instagram Bot Follower

Tags: python, selenium

I want to open an Instagram account, tap on their follower and follow all their followers. So I've written a selenium program. This code opens profile, then login with my username and password then tap on the followers, But after that, it doesn't follow all the followers. Please help.

```
from selenium import webdriver
class InstaBot:
   

    def __init__(self):
           self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
           self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
           self.driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/randomusername/")
       
   def get_follower(self, username, pw):
       self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[3]/a")\
           .click()
      
      
       self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name=\"username\"]")\
           .send_keys(username)
      
       self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name=\"password\"]")\
           .send_keys(pw)
 
       self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type="submit"]')\
           .click()
 
       self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div/div/section/div/button")\
           .click()
 
       self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[2]/a")\
           .click()

       
       follow = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/ul/div/li[3]/div/div[2]")

       i =1

       for follower in follow:
            if(i !=1):
                self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/ul/div/li[1]/div/div[3]")\
                    .click()

                i += 1   
      


       
 
 
my_bot = InstaBot()
my_bot.get_follower('username', 'pw')
```

Comment: First off, you'd likely want to investigate the instagram api: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/

Comment: Is there an error message? Or which step does the failure happen at?

Answer (score 0):

The last two xpaths suggest you're only finding one element.

Try `print(len(follow))` and it should match the number of elements you're expecting.

And then when you iterate through the `follow` list, that xpath is selecting one element in the DOM, the same element each time. You're not doing anything with the previous step so I don't think that's even necessary--you just need a better xpath. One that will select all of the elements you want to click

If this doesn't get you what you need (and you decide not to ditch it for the API) then I can help more tonight

Also this is a great case for enumerate. It handles the incrementing logic for you

```
       for i, follower in enumerate(follow):
            if i == 1: continue
            self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/ul/div/li[1]/div/div[3]")\
                    .click()
```

Answer (score 0):

The last two xpaths suggest you're only finding one element.

Try print(len(follow)) and it should match the number of elements you're expecting.

And then when you iterate through the follow list, that xpath is selecting one element in the DOM, the same element each time. You're not doing anything with the previous step so I don't think that's even necessary--you just need a better xpath. One that will select all of the elements you want to click

If this doesn't get you what you need (and you decide not to ditch it for the API) then I can help more tonight

Also this is a great case for enumerate. It handles the incrementing logic for you

```
 here for i, follower in enumerate(follow):
        if i == 1: continue
        self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/ul/div/li[1]/div/div[3]")\
                .click()
```

Comment: Hi. There is some text in your code.   Please consider using comment syntax inside block of code.